# Find new first integral of DE System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am trying to find two first integrals of the following system:
$$\begin{cases}x' = x+z\\
y'= y \\
z'=z + y^2 \end{cases}$$
A first integral can be found considering only the system in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for $y$ and $z$. Using the integrating factors $\mu_1 = \frac{1}{y^2}$ and $\mu_2 = \frac{1}{(z-y^2)^2}$ we can obtain the function $$H_1(y,z) = \sqrt{\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2}}=\frac{z}{y} -y$$ which is a first integral of the $y,z$ system, hence a first integral of the system in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Now I'm trying to get another first integral, functionally independent to $H_1$, but can't really find a way to do it unless I use PDE's, which I want to avoid.

Any help on how to get it will be appreciated! Thanks.

EDIT: by first integral I refer to a function $H(x,y,z)$ such that $$H' = \left<\nabla H, (x',y',z') \right> = 0.$$

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "first integral", maybe you are using a book that defines this expression, you could quote the book. Also, the equation for $y'$ yields the trivial solution $y=Ae^t$, from which you could directly solve for $z(t)$ and then for $x(t)$.

Comment: Just edited the post clarifying what a first integral is. @RianKoja.

Comment: I don’t want to solve the system, already know how to do that. I’m asking how to find another first integral.

Comment: What is your goal in finding a conservation law for your system? It is possible to derive such a conserved quantity (if there is a nontrivial conservation law for your system) systematically but it is very time-consuming.

Comment: @MrYouMath There isn't really a goal in finding such law. Just curiosity on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found another first integral. Since this is an actual answer to the question I made, I though it would be better to post it as an answer instead of editing the original question. Here it goes:

It is important to note that $$\left(\frac{x}{y} \right)' = \frac{x'y-xy'}{y^2} = \frac{(x+z)y -xy }{y^2} = \frac{z}{y} $$
hence, $$\left(\frac{x}{y} - y \right)' = \frac{z}{y} - y = H_1(y,z)$$ And we've seen already that this is a first integral. Again, using $y'=y$ we have that $y'' = 1$. Therefore:
$$\left(H_1(y,z)\ln|y|\right)' = H_1'\ln|y| + H_1(z,y)\frac{1}{y}y = H_1(z,y) = \frac{z}{y} - y$$
since $H_1' = 0$. Thus we shall consider
$$H_2(x,y,z) = \frac{x}{y} - y - \left(\frac{z}{y} - y \right)\ln|y|$$
as another first integral, clearly functionally independent to the previous one -it even has a different variable-.

Just as @Mefitico said, I don't know any systematic ways to actually finding such functions. It's all "trial and error", or playing with the system's functions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any systematic method for finding SODE first integrals. I can make a suggestion here if it helps you:

Note that the expression you gave for the first integral :

$$
\langle \nabla H ,(\dot{x},\dot{y},\dot{z})\rangle
$$

Can be rewritten as:

$$
[H_x,H_y,H_z] \left[
 \begin{array}{ccc} 
1 && 0 && 1 \\ 
0 && 1 && 0 \\ 
0 && 1 && y \\ 
\end{array} \right] \left[\begin{array}{c} 
x \\ 
y \\ 
z \\ 
\end{array} \right] 
$$

Note the transpose of the matrix in the middle:
$$
 \left[
 \begin{array}{ccc} 
1 && 0 && 0 \\ 
0 && 1 && 1 \\ 
1 && 0 && y \\ 
\end{array} \right] 
$$

The determinant is $y$, so basically we can look for solutions of the following forms:

$$
 \left[\begin{array}{c} 
H_x \\ 
H_y \\ 
H_z \\ 
\end{array} \right] =
 \left[
 \begin{array}{ccc} 
1 && 0 && 0 \\ 
1/y && 1 && -1/y \\ 
-1/y && 0 && 1/y \\ 
\end{array} \right] v(x,y,z)
$$

With $v$ orthogonal to $(x,y,z)$. Examples may be:
$v=[-y,x,0]^T$, $v=[0,-z,y]^T$,$v=[-z,0,x]^T$, and any of those times a function $g(x,y,z)$.

We also need that a function $H$ may be found with this gradient. Actually, if assuming that:
$$
 \left[\begin{array}{c} 
H_x \\ 
H_y \\ 
H_z \\ 
\end{array} \right] = \nabla \phi
$$

Then by [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) is is possible to find H from a guess $v(x,y,z)$. Not sure if the results found will actually satisfy you.

Comment: That's a very interesting way to look at it. Thanks